# .htaccess url rewrites break facebook share

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod-rewrite to make pretty urls. For example http://centraltrack.com/Nightlife/5936/That-Happened/Scenes-From-Friday-Nights-Pop-That-Party-at-Sons-of-Hermann-Hall is using the page http://centraltrack.com/_source/article.php?id=5936. Now when you share a link on facebook it links to the error page instead of the correct page. The Facebook linter pulls in all the correct data, so I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

Again, when you share the not pretty url above, it works and when you share the pretty one, it links to the error page instead. Everything on the site works fine, sharing on Facebook just doesn't work.

Here is how I'm rewriting the links in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^_source - [L]
RewriteRule ^images - [L]
RewriteRule ^login - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ _source/article.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Works for me. I took http://centraltrack.com/Nightlife/5936/That-Happened/Scenes-From-Friday-Nights-Pop-That-Party-at-Sons-of-Hermann-Hall and shared it on Facebook and then clicked the link and I got to the right place

Comment: Let me give a little more info. If you share using the facebook share button on the page. It always works. If you just paste the link into facebook, it does not.
![Screenshot 1](http://i.share.pho.to/62e768d0_o.png).
![Screenshot 2](http://i.share.pho.to/c667eeb9_o.png).
@WizKid

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs